# How to zip all outputs (*.csv and *.tiff) in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, zip

I use this command

```bash
! zip -r results.zip . -i *.csv *.pdf
```

in Jupyter Notebook(Python 3.7.10) in order to zip all the output files. But, it shows

> zip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Can anyone suggest what I miss?

Comment: Are you using linux?

Comment: no, I use window. It seems like this command work in linux system. How do I apply this to zip all .csv and .pdf file.

Comment: You have to specify that in question that which is your working environment, anyway I will edit my answer. Look there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are trying to use,[`os.system()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.html#os.system):
If you are using linux

```
import os 
os.system("zip -r results.zip . -i *.csv *.pdf")
#OR
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen("zip -r results.zip . -i *.csv *.pdf")
```

If you aren't using linux, in windows. There is library called [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), you can use it:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os

filesname=os.listdir("<path or empty") # Or you can alternately use glob inside `with` ZipFile
# Empty means working folder 

with ZipFile('output.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".csv") and file.endswith(".pdf"):
            myzip.write(file)
```

Comment: I want to save all the outputs as .zip. This command works in googlelab but it does not work with jupyter notebook.

Comment: @tassaneel try ngao5ry

Comment: neither works. The last one show  **File "<ipython-input-58-e5b96c2869ec>", line 1 subprocess.Popen(zip -r results.zip . -i *.csv *.pdf) **
                                                    ^
                    **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**

Comment: Thank you very much. After I keep searching the solution, I will install `conda install -c conda-forge posix` and try to running unix in jupyter notebook too.

Comment: I have tried the latest one. The syntax is correct but there are no files in the zip folder. Let me study more. I am from the biological backgroud and I need to learn more on coding stuff but thanks for your explanation. It extremely helps.

Answer (score 0):

On modern Windows the Zip tool is `Tar`

It is not well documented nor as easy to use as most 3rd Party zippers thus you would need to custom wrap your OS call.

generally the following should be good enough

`Tar -a -cf results.zip  *.csv *.pdf`

However if there are not one or other type the response will complete for the valid group, but with a very cryptic response:-

```
Tar: : Couldn't visit directory: No such file or directory
Tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```